# Authentication to Twitter API 1.1 ( with JavaScript ) to search tweets

Tags: javascript, twitter, dojo, twitter-oauth, esri

I am customizing a storymap (MapTour Template ) by Esri adding a functionality to search geolocated Tweets from the public stream, but new Twitter API require authentication.
I created an account and registered my app to obtain keys and tokens but I always get error 403.

Here is the code for authentication:

```
function oAuth(kwArgs) {

    var CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var token = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var tokenSecret = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    var access = {
        consumer: {
                    key: CONSUMER_KEY,
                    secret: CONSUMER_SECRET
            },  
             user: {
                    key: token,
                    secret: tokenSecret
                },

        sig_method: "HMAC-SHA1"

    };

    kwArgs.headers= { 
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

                 };

    // our request will be made with the HTTP GET verb

    return OAuth.sign("GET", kwArgs, access);

}
```

And here is the code where I request the tweets:

```
function searchTwitter() {

    var query = dojo.byId("twitter_input").value;
    var geocode = "42.37355,12.88290,1000km";


    try {

        var results = esri.request(oAuth({
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            url : "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json",
            content : {
                q : query,
                geocode : geocode,
                count : "100",
                include_entities : "false",
                result_type : "recent",
            },
            callbackParamName : "callback",

        }));
        results.then(addTweets);



    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.toString());
    }
};
```

What am I missing?